# devise redirect after sign up not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

have gone through some of the answers on stack and also read the devise documentation to implement this.
i wanted to Redirect to a specific page on successful sign up (registration). on the devise documentation have added the

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       '/account/new' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
end
```

in the application controller and also in the registration contoller but still its not working. what have i done wrong?
am using rails 5 with devise master branch

Comment: place debugger in the method and check it gets called or not.

Comment: you need to restart your server after putting this code

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and I realized that if your user (or resource) is inactive after registration (if for instance, you have devise set up to require email confirmation to activate), a different method is called (`after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)`). But I had to do this in a custom registrations controller, not in ApplicationController https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in.